# how to check if a checkbox on a form is selected?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with checkboxes. And I want to check if a specific checkbox is checked.
I try it like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate",function(value) {
  //var user_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
        var id = $('#my_form').closest('form').attr('id');

        console.log(id);
        var ka = $('#ID').val();
        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked')  && $(#my_form':checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
        console.log("checkbox checked; dont check duplicate email");
        return true;
        }
        else{
        console.log("checkbox not checked; check duplicate email");
         if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(":checked"))
        {
            console.log('hoi');
}
        console.log(ka);
        return false;
        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };
```

and this is the html:

```
 <div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2 contactpersonen-email1 required checkDuplicate" id="contactpersonen_email1" name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but every time it only goes to the else

it is a accordian. So every time if you add a contact the id changed:

```
<div class="contact-label span11 rights" id="formid">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canorder_0" id="contactpersonen_canorder_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canorder_0">Mag border plaatsen</label>

             <input type="checkbox" class="required checkTotal" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" id="contactpersonen_canseestock_2"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">Mag goederen afhalen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0">Mag orders inzien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0" id="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0">Mag bezorgadressen aanpassen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0">Mag netto prijs zien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0" id="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0">Mag facturen en creditfacturen inzien</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0" id="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0">Mag wijzigingen doorgeven</label>
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>
```

oke, I have it now like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate",function(value) {
  //var user_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
        var id = $('#my_form').closest('form').attr('id');
    var hallo = $('form').attr('id');
console.log(hallo);
        console.log(id);
        var ka = $('#ID').val();
        if ($('#contactpersonen_canseestock_2 input:checked').val() == "1") {
        console.log("checkbox checked; dont check duplicate email");
        return true;
        }
        else{
        console.log("checkbox not checked; check duplicate email");
   //if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(":checked"))
if($('#my_form:checkbox:checked').length == 1)
        {
            console.log('hoi');
}
        console.log(ka);
        return false;
        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };

<div class="contact-label span2">
      <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
      <div class="contact-input-field">
        <input type="text" class="input-text span2 contactpersonen_email required checkDuplicate" id="contactpersonen_email" name="contactpersonen_email"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
```

but still only goes in the else

```
<div class="contact-label span11 rights" id="formid">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canorder_0" id="contactpersonen_canorder_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canorder_0">Mag order plaatsen</label>

             <input type="checkbox" class="required checkTotal" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseestock_0" id="contactpersonen_canseestock_2"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseestock_0">Mag goederen afhalen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeorders_0">Mag orders inzien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0" id="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canaddaddress_0">Mag bezorgadressen aanpassen</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0" id="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseeprice_0">Mag netto prijs zien</label>

              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0" id="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseecredit_0">Mag facturen en creditfacturen inzien</label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
              <input type="checkbox" class="input-text" value="Y" name="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0" id="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0"></input>
              <label class="checkbox" for="contactpersonen_canseepickup_0">Mag wijzigingen doorgeven</label>
            </div>
          </div>        
        </div>       
      </div>
```

This is a image:
[image]

so and that is wrong. Because if only that checkbox is checked then no validation has to triggered.

Comment: I see no element in your example that has the ID of `contactpersonen_canseestock_2`. You also have typos in `$(#my_form':checkbox:checked')`

Comment: I update the post

Comment: still have errors, check again

Comment: ? What I have to check?

Comment: On line 7, `$(#my_form':checkbox:checked')` is an error. Typo

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question. Pay special attention to the "minimal" part of that. Also, learn [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525), and observe the errors therein.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works for me.  Give it a try.

```
if ($('#contactpersonen_canseestock_2 input:checked').val() == "1")
```

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of code in your answer, so it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.
But this is how I always do it:

```
<input id="active_box" type="checkbox" /> 

 if ($('#active_box').is(':checked')) { 
  // logic
}
```

Comment: Why you block my account??? this is all the third time!! I can also downvote every account for nothing!!!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I have no ability to block your account or do anything outside of basic user functions.

Comment: I didnt mean you. But there are users here who for fun downvote questions. And nobody do something about that. So now my account is again blocked. Because of these retards

Comment: Your question was poorly asked, poorly explained and poorly presented. All the downvotes were explained clearly and concisely.  We do not exist to do your work for you so I suggest you improve how you present your questions and your attitude.